# delphi AV in the observer pattern with interfaces

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, observer-pattern, access-violation

I would like to implement the observer pattern using Delphi.
Here are an interface `ISubject` and a class `TWeatherData` that implements an observer.

```
ISubject = interface
    procedure notifyObservers;
    procedure removeObserver(o: IObserver);
    procedure registerObserver(o: IObserver);
  end;

TWeatherData = class(TInterfacedObject, ISubject)
  private
    observers: TList;
    FTemperature: Double;
    FHumidity: Double;
    FPressure: Double;
  public
    // ...
    procedure notifyObservers;
    procedure setMeasurements(ATemperature, AHumidity, APressure: Double);
  end;
```

I get an *Access Violation* about *read of address* when `TWeatherData.notifyObservers` executes

```
procedure TWeatherData.notifyObservers;
var
  observer: ^IObserver;
begin
  for observer in observers do
    observer.Update(FTemperature, FHumidity, FPressure); //oops -> there raised AV.
end;


procedure TWeatherData.setMeasurements(ATemperature, AHumidity,
  APressure: Double);
begin
  measurementsChanged; // and this one calls TWeatherData.notifyObservers;
end;
```

The main program:

```
    weatherStation := TWeatherData.Create;
    currentConditionalDisplay := TCurrentConditionalDisplay.Create(weatherStation);
    weatherStation.setMeasurements(100.0, 58.0, 756.0); // a stack head of exception.
```

Answer (score 5):

The AV is raised, because you only store a pointer to `IObserver`. But this is a weak reference and the Observer-Instance has already gone away.

Use a `TList<IObserver>` instead as shown in [Nicks blog](http://www.nickhodges.com/post/Delphi-and-the-Observer-Pattern.aspx).

If you do not want the Generics then you should use `TInterfaceList` as shown [here](http://delphipatterns.blog.com/2011/03/29/observer/)